# Scikit-learn style "pipelines" in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone has implemented something akin to [scikit-learn's pipelines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) in R?  They're a useful way of chaining together multiple operations on a dataset, e.g. PCA + RBM + logistic regression.

It seems to me that the `transform` method in scikit-learn is similar to the `predict` S3 method in R, and the `fit` method in scikit learn is similar to calling a function in R that returns an S3 object with a fit method, so something like this could be possible.

(Note that magrittr's forward pipe doesn't really solve the problem: scikit-learn's pipelines themselves have fit and predict methods, which makes them reusable and applicable to new data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old as hell, but thought I'd add this for anyone coming to this page via Google like I did: https://www.r-bloggers.com/machine-learning-pipelines-for-r/.

Answer (score 5):

[mlrCPO](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlrCPO) seems a bit more robust. It is from the same group that makes [MLR](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/index.html), which I would call R's scikit-learn.

It provides piping operators that let you concatenate complex preprocessing operations (from the docs):

```
task = iris.task
task %<>>% cpoScale(scale = FALSE) %>>% cpoPca() %>>%  # pca
cpoFilterChiSquared(abs = 3) %>>%  # filter
cpoModelMatrix(~ 0 + .^2)  # interactions
```

There's also the package [recipes](https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/) from the [tidymodels](https://github.com/tidymodels/tidymodels) metapackage. This one is developed by the same people behind tidyverse (dplyr, etc.). It should be easier to follow if you're already familiar with dplyr and friends. Here's a snip from the docs:

```
library(recipes)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
sonar_rec <- recipe(Class ~ ., data = Sonar) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors())
```